# Are Immutable.js data structures functors?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, functor, immutable.js

Are Immutable.js data structures functors?

My gut says yes:

```
Map({ a: 1, b: 2 }).map(x => 10 * x)
// Map { a: 10, b: 20 }
```

I'm looking for an in-depth explanation of the degree to which Immutable.js structures are functors. Do they follow both the identity and composition laws? Are all of the `Collections` functors or is it just `Maps`, `Lists`, and `Sequences`?

Comment: Anything supporting a `map` method should really obey the identity law. A set is only provisionally a functor: you have to assume that the equality tests involved are sufficiently strict. If "equal" elements can be distinguished in any way, then the composition law will fail. I don't know anything about JS collections, so I can't speak to those specifically.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer! Do you mind expanding on 'distinguishing "equal" elements'? What type of equality check would cause the composition law to fail? Duck / structural typing? [other] typing?

Comment: Sure. Suppose you have a set of numbers. The `Collections` set seems to use `SameValueZero` equality (see [MDN](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262)), which (among other things) considers `+0` and `-0` equal. Suppose you have a function `f` that takes `false` to `-0` and `true` to `+0`. Suppose that `g` uses `SameValue` comparison to test for equality to `-0`. If you map over the set `{True, False}` with `g . f`, you'll get back `{True, False}`. If you map over that set with `f`, you'll get `{-0}` (or maybe `{+0}`). If you map over that result with `g`, you'll get `{True}` or `{False}`.

Comment: Another important point is that when you're considering the composition law, you have to assume that the functions you're mapping over containers either have no side effects or have side effects that commute with each other. If `f` prints "Hi" and `g` prints "Bye", mapping the composition will print something like "HiByeHiBye..." while mapping each in sequence will give something like "HiHiByeBye".